# phpMyAdmin: Can't log in with user other than root

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I just installed the IIS server (Windows Server 2008 R2), together with PHP 7.2.8 and MySQL 8.0.12. I created some users in the workbench, e.g. 'pma'/'pmapassword' and gave it full privileges, but when I try to log in, I get the following error:

> mysqli_real_connect(): PHP was built without openssl extension, can't
>   send password encrypted

and

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'pma'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

However, when I log in with my root account, it works! Obviously I need more than a root account and I would really like to know why this is happening, as well how to fix it!

For now my config.inc.php is real minimal (but I tried the 'config' login method as well):

```
<?php
 $cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'my_blowfish_secret_here';  // use here a 
 value of your choice

 $i=0;
 $i++;
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'cookie';
?>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

**Edit:** Here is the [php.ini](https://pastebin.com/FwPtXc3E).

Comment: Kindly check php.ini or share the same

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I have added [a link to the php.ini](https://pastebin.com/FwPtXc3E) in the OP as well.

Answer (score 0):

While creating the user there is an option to choose a host, so that host should be the same from where you trying to log in